# "The string supplied did not seem to be a phone number" phonenumbers modual

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, python-phonenumber

I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong, I keep getting the error message

> The string supplied did not seem to be a phone number

I'm trying to make a little app that does a lot of things with phone numbers like give the location and stuff like that.

Here's the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import phonenumbers
from phonenumbers import geocoder
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter.font import Font


root = tk.Tk()


canvas =tk.Canvas(root, width=600, height=300, bg="#000000")
canvas.grid(columnspan=4, rowspan=4)

root.title("phOsint")

textbox = Entry(root, width=40,)
textbox.grid(column=1, row=2)


myFont = Font(
    family="Magneto",
    size=12,
    slant="roman")

logo = Image.open("anonlogorm.png",).convert("RGB")
logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(logo)
logo_label = tk.Label(image=logo, borderwidth=0)
logo_label.image = logo
logo_label.grid(column=1, row=0)

instructions = tk.Label(root, text="Enter in a phone number, let's see where it's located ;)", fg="light green", bg="black", font=myFont)
instructions.grid(columnspan=3, column=0, row=1)

def button_command():
    phoneNumber = phonenumbers.parse(str(textbox))
    phoneNumber.strip()
    print(geocoder.description_for_number(phoneNumber, "en"))



browse_text = tk.StringVar()
browse_btn = tk.Button(root, textvariable=browse_text, command=button_command, bg="purple", fg="white", height=2, width=10, font=myFont)
browse_text.set("Show Me")
browse_btn.grid(column=1, row=3)




canvas =tk.Canvas(root, width=600, height=250, bg="#000000")
canvas.grid(columnspan=3,)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you not think that we can only help you if you tell us *which* string was supposedly not a phone number?

Comment: You mean "I" since I got the answer I was looking for, lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have passed the name of `textbox` to `phonenumbers.parse()` inside `button_command()`, use `textbox.get()` instead.

Also the result of `phonenumbers.parse()` is not a string, you cannot call `strip()` on it:

```py
def button_command():
    phoneNumber = phonenumbers.parse(textbox.get().strip())
    print(geocoder.description_for_number(phoneNumber, "en"))
```